# Acesso ao caminho foi negado ao fazer "File.WriteAllText"

Tags: c#

Segue código:

```
public static string pathname = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString()) + @"\Arquivo_Principal";

if (!File.Exists($@"{pathname}\Musica\{nomemusica}.txt"))
{
    File.WriteAllText($@"{pathname}\Musica\{nomemusica}.txt", letramusica, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Alguma solução?

Comment: Você está rodando o VS como administrador? é Windows Forms? Tá com cara de permissão na pasta..

Comment: Certo, execute como admin a aplicação, verifique permissões de escrita no Windows nessa pasta, na aba segurança.. verifique também se esss paths estai corretos {pathname}

Comment: imagino que no outro notebook exista a pasta certo? ...\musica\

Comment: Acho que o problema acontece isso, quando não executa exe como adm

Comment: Então, não há necessidade de executar como Adm, porém você terá que conceder permissão na pasta, vai no Explorer, propriedade na pasta e aba segurança.. e conceda permissões lá.. principalmente se a aplicação estiver por ex no Desktop.. aí o nível de segurança é maior, e por ai vai..

Comment: Cada vez que usuário instalar `.exe`, vai ficar muito chato de ir lá em permissão > propriedade > segurança. Não existe uma forma de tirar essa permissão ? Apenas instalar e executar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288444/how-to-give-read-write-permissions-to-a-folder-during-installation-using-net

Comment: Cara, Windows Installer da Micrososft da muito a dor de cabeça. Resolvi a usar Inno Setup. Já resolve tudo e de graça.

Comment: Desisto !!! Dúvida alguém resolver esse problema.